# When scrolling expandable list view textview values change

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with two tabs, one of the tabs has a fragment with expandable list view.

When the tab is selected a background operation is being called and collects all data and set it in the proper arrays.

i can see the expandable list view and the relevant child's however when I scroll up and down I can see that the value for the textview of the child are changed.

on the base_expandable_adapter I am working with view holders for the group and child's. what I cant figure out though is why the values are changing. do you have any though how this can be resolved?

```
public class S_GRP_EXP_LST_ADAPTER extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{

    private String TAG="EXP_LST_ADAPTER";
    private Context CNTX;
    private List<S_GRP_get_set>S_GRP_PARENT=new ArrayList<S_GRP_get_set>() ;
    private HashMap<String, List<S_GRP_get_set_child>> listDataChildResult = new HashMap<String, List<S_GRP_get_set_child>>();
    private ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder();





    public S_GRP_EXP_LST_ADAPTER(List<S_GRP_get_set> _S_GRP_PARENT,HashMap<String, List<S_GRP_get_set_child>>  _listDataChildResult,Context _CNTX)
    {
        this.S_GRP_PARENT=_S_GRP_PARENT;
        this.listDataChildResult=_listDataChildResult;
        this.CNTX=_CNTX;

        Log.i(TAG, ""+S_GRP_PARENT.size() + ""+ listDataChildResult.size());
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        Log.i(TAG, "getGroupCount() invoked");
        return S_GRP_PARENT.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        Log.i(TAG, "getChildrenCount() invoked");
        return listDataChildResult.get(S_GRP_PARENT.get(groupPosition).Get_Group_Name()).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        Log.i(TAG, "getGroup() invoked");
        return S_GRP_PARENT.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        Log.i(TAG, "getChild() invoked");
        return listDataChildResult.get(S_GRP_PARENT.get(groupPosition).Get_Group_Name()).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        Log.i(TAG, "getGroupId() invoked");
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        Log.i(TAG, "getChildId() invoked");
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        Log.i(TAG, "hasStableIds() invoked");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "getGroupView() invoked");

        View parentView =convertView;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.CNTX.getSystemService
                  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(parentView==null)
        {

            parentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_index_list_layout, parent, false);

            holder.grp_name=(TextView)parentView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Grp_Name);
            holder.grp_mtrc=(TextView)parentView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Grp_Mtrc);
            holder.grp_health=(TextView)parentView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Grp_Health_Title);
            parentView.setTag(holder);
        }

        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) parentView.getTag();
        }

        holder.grp_name.setText(S_GRP_PARENT.get(groupPosition).Get_Group_Name());
        holder.grp_mtrc.setText(S_GRP_PARENT.get(groupPosition).Get_Group_mtrc());
        holder.grp_name.setText(S_GRP_PARENT.get(groupPosition).Get_Group_Name());

        return parentView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "getChildView() invoked");

        View childView=convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflaterchild = (LayoutInflater)this.CNTX.getSystemService
                  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(childView==null)
        {

            childView = inflaterchild.inflate(R.layout.group_exp_list_child_layout, parent, false);

            child_holder.grp_r_index=(TextView)childView.findViewById(R.id.tv_r_S_name_in_GRP);
            child_holder.grp_r_state=(TextView)childView.findViewById(R.id.tv_R_SRV_state);
            childView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder=(ViewHolder) childView.getTag();
        }

        child_holder.grp_r_index.setText(listDataChildResult.get(S_GRP_PARENT.get(groupPosition).Get_Grp_Name()).get(childPosition).get_srv_index());
        child_holder.grp_r_state.setText(listDataChildResult.get(S_GRP_PARENT.get(groupPosition).Get_Grp_Name()).get(childPosition).get_srv_state());

        return childView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

//class for the view holder
public class ViewHolder 

{
TextView grp_name;
TextView grp_mtrc;
TextView grp_health;
TextView grp_r_index;
TextView grp_r_state;
}


}
```

Comment: are you populating listview from server ? if so is that static or dynamic data . because listview got refresh on scroll

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: Hi, the flow is as follows:1.getting information from device 2.place all information into the arrays 3. call the list adapter and passing list and hashmap as parameters. I will share the code in a few moments

Comment: use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497559/listview-changes-records-while-scrolling .. my problem was solved... I'm faced same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello i heaved use this adapter for expandable list view 
use this:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
    private List<Home_property> data;
    int[] images_tag;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<Home_property> category,
            int[] image) {
        this._context = context;
        images_tag = image;
        data = category;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        txtListChild.setTypeface(Fontfamily.getFont(_context));
        txtListChild
                .setText(data.get(groupPosition).subcats.get(childPosition).subcatnam);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return data.get(groupPosition).subcats.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }
        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        ImageView header = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(Fontfamily.getFont(_context));
        try {
            lblListHeader.setText(data.get(groupPosition).catnam);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

        }   

        header.setBackgroundResource(images_tag[groupPosition]);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I see the main difference is that you are not using viewholder class, do you believe that this causing the issue?

Comment: Good news :-), it seems that the main issue was the holders i used on the child and group views. once I removed them the data stay the same. the main question though is why holders will create this behavior? aren't they suppose to increase the performance and reduce memory usage? do you have any idea?